# over image preventing button from being clicked

Tags: css, hover

Good afternoon
in an html site, I have one rectangular image and when I hover over it a second image pops out. The second image is bigger than the original image and it on top of a button.
The problem is, I can't click the button, it always triggers the hover image.
How can fix this so that I can click the button?
Here's a fiddle

HTML:

```
    <li id="menu-item-2365" class="positionabsolute menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-2365 has-image"><a href="como-ajudar/donativos/"
 class="menu-image-title-hide menu-image-hovered"><span class="menu-image-hover-wrapper">
    <img width="126" height="38" src="http://piq.codeus.net/static/media/userpics/piq_307293_400x400.png" class="menu-image menu-image-title-hide" style="position:absolute" alt=""><img width="126" height="145" src="http://piq.codeus.net/static/media/userpics/piq_307293_400x400.png" style="position:absolute" class="hovered-image menu-image-title-hide" alt="" ></span></a></li>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="click" style="margin-left:50px" />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u15qbh6w/

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you want the button to be on top of the image or do you want it behind the image but still want it to be clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `display: none` to the second image and if it is hovered, then `display: initial`

So the css of your example would look like that:

```
.menu-item a.menu-image-hovered img.hovered-image,
.menu-item a.menu-image-hovered:hover img.menu-image {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.menu-item a.menu-image-hovered img.hovered-image {
  display: none;
}
.menu-item a.menu-image-hovered:hover img.hovered-image {
  display: initial;
  opacity: 1;
}
```